# Take different values from a String and convert them to Double Values

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

In my code, I'm asking the user to input three different values divided by a blank space.
Then, those three different values I would like to assign them to three different **Double** variables.

I have tried by assigning the first character of such string to my double variables but I haven't been able to succeed.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
int decision = message();
String newDimensions;
double newHeight, newWidth, newLength;

if(decision == 1){
  newDimensions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the desired amount to be added" + 
                                            "\nto each dimension." +
"\nNOTE: First value is for Height, second for Width, third for Length" +
"\nAlso, input information has to have a blank space between each value." +
"\nEXAMPLE: 4 8 9");

newHeight = Double.parseDouble(newDimensions.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the input, split it by a whitespace and parse each Double. This code does not sanitize the input.

```
        String input = "12.4 19.8776 23.3445";
        String[] split = input.split(" ");
        for(String s : split)
        {
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(s));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Take input from user.
2. split that line using delimeter space i.e " ".
3. inside for loop change each index element to double.By using Double.parseDouble(splitted[i]);

Answer (score 1):

You could first split the input using [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and then parse each variable using Double.parseDouble [Double.parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) to read them into a Double variable.

```
String[] params = newDimensions.split(" ");
newHeight = Double.parseDouble(params[0]);
newWidth = Double.parseDouble(params[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Double#parseDouble(str)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) expects a string,and you are trying to pass a character.

try this:

```
newHeight = Double.parseDouble(newDimensions.subString(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
newDimensions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...

newDimensions = newDimensions.trim();

String arr[] = newDimensions.split(" ");

double darr[] = new double[arr.length];

for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) darr[i] = Double.parseDouble(arr[i].trim());
```

There are still some defensive issues that can be taken.  Doing a trim on your parse double is kind of critical.